# How use middleware with rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 roles in my system and i want to create middleware to each role

I use `rake middleware` but this command create a lot of middlewares and I want create my own middleware and use it in my code.

what is the best way to use middleware in rails with examples ??

Answer (score 1):

I think filters are equivalent to middleware. If you want to run a method every time, you can add a `before_action` to ApplicationController. Or, you can only add to specific controllers to optimize performance.

My advice is, read Rails Guides to figuring this out. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters

Answer (score 0):

create method to check the role of user

```
def authorize_user
if(@user.user_type_id != 1)
  render json:{'error': "user is un authorized to this page"} ,status:409
  return
end
end
```

and get the method
 `before_action :authenticate_user`